# Domain search entries in resolv.conf and ifcfg-ens33 files

Tags: centos, networking, resolv.conf

In CentOS, when we modify `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33` file for multiple domain search entries, should we also manually change `/etc/resolv.conf` ?